# MariaDB 10.2 crash on innodb table corruption - trying to restore the database

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, restore, mariadb-10.2

I'm running MariaDB 10.2 on Windows and had some hard drive corruption on my server that messed up some innodb tables. Unfortunately this also affected backups, so I'm trying to dump the tables and restore them.

Problem is, even with force recovery set to 6, the server will crash when it reaches a corrupt row. Dumping the table with asc and then desc worked for one table, but not for another and any attempt to jump the row with limit and offset still crashes.

I saw that there was a `innodb_pass_corrupt_table_action=salvage` option in 10.1, but it is deprecated and ignored with 10.2. Is there a similar setting for 10.2? Are there any other options to force MySQL to dump the tables? Thanks!

Comment: "messed up"? "crash"? exact errors, mysql error log, and full version numbers would help. The [kb of innodb system variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables) is usually up to date. Freenode #mariadb or [zulip chat](https://mariadb.zulipchat.com/) might be more suitable for realtime response.

Comment: I'm currently on 10.2.21-MariaDB, and I have crc errors on my hard drive that are unrecoverable.  When MySQL hits a bad row it will post to the error log about "database page corruption" failed to read tablespace db/table. Do a page dump, then followed by notes on crc calculations, assertion failures, and information on innodb table corruption.  Finally a mysqld got exception 0xc0000005.  I've read through it all, but can't find a solution that allows me to skip bad rows and continue dumping the corrupted tables.  Mysql recovery software programs out there arent compatible with MariaDb either.

Comment: Though not a recovery tool https://github.com/jeremycole/innodb_ruby/ might be able to see bits of the tables in some form.

Comment: Really I can see the tables just fine.  It's just maybe a few hundred rows out of 54 million that have the corruption.  I can do a mysql dump on the table up until a corrupt row, and then the Mysql service stops.  If I could just keep the Mysql service from stopping when it detects a bad row, then I could dump the table and be fine with the bad rows being acceptable losses.  "innodb_pass_corrupt_table_action=salvage" seemed like the perfect settings, but it's removed from MariaDB 10.2 since xtradb is no longer integrated.